# Joining two queries together where one has a subquery

Tags: sql, join, oracle11g

Hello I want to join these two queries together. I have tried many combinations of writing and rewriting the code and I have become stuck.

The two queries I want to join are:

```
SELECT a.lastname, a.firstname
FROM athletes a,
(SELECT athlete#, COUNT(event#) 
    FROM results
    GROUP BY athlete#
    HAVING COUNT(event#) > 1 ) b 
WHERE a.athlete# = b.athlete#
ORDER BY a.lastname;
```

and

```
SELECT sc.datetime, e.name
FROM event e JOIN schedule sc USING (event#);
```

The first query does a count on the athletes having more than one event and returns the correct number of 19, when I try to add the 2nd query into the first I end up pulling most of the data from the results table.

Comment: Please edit your question with sample data and desired results, so it is clear what you are trying to do.  "Add"ing is not an operation applicable to queries.

Answer (score 0):

If you want events for athletes have competed more than once, which seems like a reasonable interpretation, then:

```
select a.lastname, a.firstname, e.name, sc.datetime
from athletes a join
     (select r.*, count(*) over (partition by athelete#) as cnt
      from results r
     ) r
     on a.athlete# = r.athelete# and cnt > 1 join
     event e
     on r.event# = e.event# join
     schedule s
     on e.event# = s.event#;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.lastname, a.firstname, sc.datetime, e.name
FROM athletes a
inner join (SELECT athlete#, COUNT(event#) 
    FROM results
    GROUP BY athlete#
    HAVING COUNT(event#) > 1 ) b  on a.athlete# = b.athlete#
inner join results r on r.athlete# =b.athlete#
inner join event e on e.event# = r.event# 
inner join schedule sc on sc.event# = e.event#
ORDER BY a.lastname;
```